# How to get android play store installed apps packages through android code?

Tags: android, package, android-applicationinfo

There are 3 types of apps in android

1. Android System apps
2. Apps installed from Android Play Store
3. Apps installed through local apk (usually installed by developers or any other source)

I get the 1st category of apps packages (i.e. System apps) using code below

```
private boolean isSystemPackage(ResolveInfo ri) {
return (ri.activityInfo.applicationInfo.flags & ApplicationInfo.FLAG_SYSTEM) != 0;
}
```

I want to get packages of 2nd category of apps on Android Device (i.e. **Apps installed from Android Play Store**)....please tell me how do i get that?

*Even if i get local installed apps (i.e. 3rd category) then i can also find my solution by ignoring 1st and 3rd category of apps packages from all packages....*

Answer (score 2):

You should use getInstallerPackageName, it retrieves the package name of the application that installed a package. This identifies which market the package came from:

http://developer.android.com/reference/android/content/pm/PackageManager.html#getInstallerPackageName%28java.lang.String%29

For the Play Store, you should check if it comes from **com.android.vending**!

Comment: The getInstallerPackageName is not a reliable call because the value returned is not reliable and can be easily fudged using the following command: "adb install -i <installer-packagename> some.apk"